# click body to change state in react to close dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a simple dropdown menu as I want different style and have more control over the behavior, but now I'm stuck in making the dropdown to be closed when user click elsewhere on the body or on other element. How can I achieve that with pure react?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
     return {
        openDropdown: false
     }
  },

  toggleDropdown: function() {
     this.setState({
         openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown
     })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <ul>
        <p onClick={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this)}>Select</p>
        <div className={this.state.openDropdown ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        </div>
      </ul>

    )
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1z5zpqeo

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the body when component loads.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdwn);
},

closeDropdwn: function() {
  this.setState({
    openDropdown: false,
  })
},
```

Comment: this will have problem if I have multiple dropdown.

Comment: Yes. In order to have multiple drop-downs, you need to save in state which dropdown is open and close only that one when clicked on body.

Answer (score -1):

I renamed your state for better understanding, also, changed your div on render to ul, li elements should never be inside any other element than ul.

Also, a bit more of spliting so it's easier to debug if needed.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            isOpenDropdown: false //rename for better understanding
        }
    },

    toggleDropdown: function(e) {
        if(e && ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.dropdown).contains(e.target)) {
            return; //Ignore click if it was inside the dropdown
    }
    this.state.isOpenDropdown ? this.closeDropdown() : this.openDropdown()
},

openDropdown: function() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeDropdown);
    this.setState({
        isOpenDropdown: true
    });
},

closeDropdown: function() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeDropdown);
    this.setState({
        isOpenDropdown: false
    });
}

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    if(this.state.isOpenDropdown){
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeDropdown);
    }
}

render: function() {
    //Changed "div" to "ul" -- LI should never be inside any element other than UL.
    return (
        <div>
        <p onClick={this.toggleDropdown.bind(this)}>Select</p>
        <ul className={this.state.isOpenDropdown ? 'show' : 'hide'}> 
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        )
}
});
```

Comment: only `li` should be inside `ul`, though anything else can be inside `li`

Comment: Didn't see there was another ul. Gonna fix that.